# Getting error when using LogEventListener

Tags: java, selenide

I am getting an error when using a LogEventListener.

When I just print something, for example in the beforeEvent method, everything is fine, but when I set any action in any method, I get this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2173)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementDescriber.selector(SelenideElementDescriber.java:67)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.ElementFinder.elementCriteria(ElementFinder.java:137)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.ElementFinder.getSearchCriteria(ElementFinder.java:130)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Alias$NoneAlias.getOrElse(Alias.java:43)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebElementSource.description(WebElementSource.java:60)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:81)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy17.is(Unknown Source)
    at com.bme.listeners.EventLogger.beforeEvent(EventLogger.java:16)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.beginStep(SelenideLogger.java:121)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.logevents.SelenideLogger.beginStep(SelenideLogger.java:57)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:81)**
```

Code:

```
public class EventLogger implements LogEventListener {

@Override
public void beforeEvent(LogEvent log) {

    if(Selenide.$("path").is(visible)) {
        System.out.println("Before Event");
    }

}

@Override
public void afterEvent(LogEvent log) {
}
```

}

Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: You write "When I print something ... everything is fine but when I set any action in any method I get this error", but your code sample only contains the printing, which you say is fine.  Please edit your code sample to ensure that it reproduces the problem you describe.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I used an if statement before printing, so I get an error in this case, but if I only use the print method, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess as to the cause of this problem is that calling `Selenide.$("path").is(visible)` causes a log event to be generated.  This would cause your listener gets called again, so `Selenide.$("path").is(visible)` gets called again, which causes another log event, so your listener gets called again, and so on and so on until the stack overflows.  However, I don't have enough of your stacktrace to be sure.  I would be more sure of this problem if you could include the stacktrace down as far as the second line in which `com.bme.listeners.EventLogger.beforeEvent` appears.

What might help is adding a boolean field to your listener that records whether it is currently logging an event, and does nothing if `beforeEvent` is called and this field is `true`:

```java
public class EventLogger implements LogEventListener {

    private boolean isCurrentlyLoggingAnEvent = false;

    @Override
    public void beforeEvent(LogEvent log) {
        if (isCurrentlyLoggingAnEvent) {
            // Prevent recursive call.
            return;
        }
    
        isCurrentlyLoggingAnEvent = true;
        try {
            if(Selenide.$("path").is(visible)) {
                System.out.println("Before Event");
            }
        }
        finally {
            isCurrentlyLoggingAnEvent = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEvent(LogEvent log) {
    }
}
```

I've used a `try`-`finally` block to ensure that the field `isCurrentlyLoggingAnEvent` is always set back to `false`, even when an exception is thrown from within the `try` block.

If you plan to put any logic in `afterEvent`, you may want to consider doing something similar there.